# How to add items in popup menu?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

In eclipse plugin development, I want to add one item (eg: Mystyle ) in popup menu.

For an instance,

Project Explorer --> Right Click -->  New --> MyStyle

How can I achieve this in eclipse plugin development?

Regards
Mathan

Answer (score 25):

Something like this should do it (following [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=rview&goto=325368&th=106355)):

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
         locationURI=
         "popup:org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer#PopupMenu?after=additions">
         <command
               commandId="myplugin.command.mycommand"
               icon="icons/etool16/mycommand.png"
               label="Run mycommand"
               mnemonic="M1+P"
               tooltip="Do something with this project">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

See [Menucontribution](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_menus.html)

> Defines an ordered set of additions to the command UI structure. The defined elements will be added into the command UI structure at the location specified by the **`locationURI`** element.
>
> This should be the starting point for all contributions into menus, toolbars or trim, wherever they occur in the UI.
>
> - **`locationURI`** - A URI specification that defines the insertion point at which the contained additions will be added.
>     The format for the URI is comprised of three basic parts:
>
>   - Scheme: One of "menu", "popup" or "toolbar.
>       Indicates the type of the manager used to handle the contributions
>   - Id: This is either the id of an existing menu, a view id or the id of the editor 'type'
>   - Query: The query format is `<placement>=<id>` where: `<placement>` is either "before" or "after" and `<id>` is the id of an existing menu item

[image: Show Readme Action]

See also <del>[`org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm)</del>, **[`org.eclipse.ui.menus`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm)**-extension point with a `menuContribution` that has its `locationURI`-attribute pointing to **`popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions`**.
Warning, as [Prashant Bhate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686478/prashant-bhate) mentions in the comment, that package `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` is deprecated.
See question [Missing link between `objectContribution` and command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915550/missing-link-between-objectcontribution-and-command) for more.

Comment: I think org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus is depricated now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915550/missing-link-between-objectcontribution-and-command

Comment: @Prashant: very good point. I have edited my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: @VonC The eclipse.org links in your answer are now broken.

Comment: @reprogrammer all links are now restored.

Comment: this question never received an answer; how to add to the file->new menu?

Comment: This looks very simple. But it does not work for me. I am using Eclipse PDE 3.8 for development. When I install the new plug-in I developed Eclipse is not showing the menu item which is added. Instead of that it shows a few item of the existing menu blank. What could be the reason

Comment: @ShibinFrancis 8 years later, it might be best to ask a new question: a lot might have changed since my old answer.

Answer (score 9):

it took me awhile to solve this exact problem just now, so I'll put up answer to OP's question (add to File->New menu).

**Where to Contribute (common.new.menu)**

thanks to this post, I discovered that you want to contribute to popup:common.new.menu?after=new. why, you ask? heck if I know; but it works.

- [Stack Overflow - Menu contribution for popupsubmenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357074/menu-contribution-for-popupsubmenu?rq=1)
- [Stack Overflow - Adding an entry in a submenu of a popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2073325/adding-an-entry-in-a-submenu-of-a-popup?lq=1)

**Result**

(When C/C++ is active perspective)

[image]

(When 'not' C/C++ as active perspective)

[image]

Here is my example plugin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="com.justin.debug.SampleHandler"
            id="com.justin.debug.commands.sampleCommand"
            name="Sample Command">
      </command>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=new">
         <command
               commandId="com.justin.debug.commands.sampleCommand"
               icon="icons/sample.gif"
               label="New Root Command From Justin"
               style="push">
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
                  <equals
                        value="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.CPerspective">
                  </equals>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
      <menuContribution
            locationURI="popup:common.new.menu?after=new">
         <menu
               id="org.ecilpse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer.helloJustin"
               label="Hello Justin">
            <command
                  commandId="com.justin.debug.commands.sampleCommand"
                  icon="icons/sample.gif"
                  label="New Submenu Command From Justin"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

I added an important part here, the 'visibleWhen' parameter. This only shows *New Root Command From Justin* when in the C/C++ perspective. It turns out to be tricky to figure that out, thus my inclusion in example. Here are useful resources I dug up while researching that:

- [Eclipse - Command Core Expressions](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions)
- [Eclipse RCP Commands Part 3: visibleWhen and Core Expressions](http://hermanlintvelt.blogspot.com/2009/06/eclipse-rcp-commands-part-3-visiblewhen.html)

I dug up the name of the C Perspective *org.eclipse.cdt.ui.CPerspective* by painfully digging through the plugin.xml of the org.eclipse.cdt.ui plugin.

now if anyone could tell me how to easily look these uri/resources/properties up in the future... omg.

Comment: The approach doesn't works when the view is changed to Package Explorer. Any suggestions.