# Menu contribution for popupsubmenu?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

In eclipse plugin development i could add files in toolbar, menu and popupmenu by using menu contribution.

In my project I want to add a set of files in the popupsubmenu,

eg : Like the following

Project Explorer -> Right Click -> New -> Annotation, Class, Enum ....

I want to add my files abc,def and xyz.. under the new menu item

What is the locationuri for popupsubmenu ?

Help me on this

Thanks in advance

Regards
Mathan

Comment: Just added location uri for project explorer (sorry, I initially explored the *package* explorer)

Comment: If I wish to put the above menu inside any already existing menu, then what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, see "[How to add items in popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22289660/6309)" (from [justinmreina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3159066/justinmreina)) for more on adding an entry to a menu.

Note the second part of this answer is for *package* explorer.

For *project* explorer, the location uri would be:

```
menu:common.new.menu?after=new
```

---

(Example, but for package explorer)

Something like (if you follow [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg67648.html)):

```
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="menu:new?after=myGroup1">
            <command
                commandId="com.mycpy.myproject.ui.pluginXX.commands.openNewWizard"
                disabledIcon="icons/disabled/new.gif"
                icon="icons/enabled/new.gif"
                id="com.mycpy.myproject.ui.pluginXX.menus.openNewWizard"
                label="PluginXX"
                tooltip="PluginXX"
                mnemonic="XX">
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
```

I would use as locationuri:

```
menu:new?after=additions
```

(no need to define a custom group here)

See also [Wiki "Menu Contributions"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions#menu:)

Comment: This locationuri is working for main menu, however its not working for popup which is coming from project explorer.
Also i tried with this locationuri "popup:new?after=additions".
How to bring my submenuId in popup ?

Comment: here is a response I just posted that adds more context/example to this OP's question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu/22289660#22289660