# Adding an entry in a submenu of a popup

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm building a plugin, and adding an entry to the context menu (right-click on a folder in the  project tree).

So far it works, following this tutorial:
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JFaceWizards/index.html

The problem is that it's adding my entry in the root of the context menu. Since my entry refers to a "New XXX" wizard, I want it to go to the "New" submenu.

It seems like I would have to set the correct locationURI or menuPath in my plugin.xml. However I can't find the locationURI or menuPath corresponding to that submenu. How can I find that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new contributions are menu ID based, not menu path based. So it should be something like:

```
<menuContribution
locationURI="menu:file?after=additions" />
```

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu) for an example of `locationUri`.
See [Menu Extension](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions#menu%3A) for more. The exact id is either:

- found in the existing plugin.xml from the menu or
- determined with [plugin Spy](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/04/02/eclipse-menu-contribution-uris/)

[image]

See "[How to add items in popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22289660/6309)" (from [justinmreina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3159066/justinmreina)) for more on adding an entry to a menu.

Comment: here is another detailed example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu/22289660#22289660

Answer (score 0):

If you've created a plugin for a 'New XXX' wizard, you can add it inside the 'New' menu that you see when you right-click inside the Navigator by customizing the perspective.

Go to Window -> Customize Perspective and click on the Shortcuts tab. You should see 'New XXX'. Select it and you're good to go.

[image]