# Missing link between objectContribution and command

Tags: eclipse, command

When using the `objectContribution`-element (which is part of the [`org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_basicext_popupMenus.htm)-extension point), I often (practically always) want to delegate to some command instead of  implementing some action myself (since usually, I have the command and a handler already implemented). I'm doing this by using `ICommandService` and `IHandlerService`, but it feels there should be a way to achieve this programmatically. I could use `viewerContribution` instead of `objectContribution`, but then I would lose the easy way of showing the menu entry only when certain object types are selected. Ideally, I would like to use the enablement-checks that already exist for my handlers to apply to the menu entry defined by the `objectContribution`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's what I was missing: instead of using the `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`-extension point, I had to use the [`org.eclipse.ui.menus`](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_menus.html)-extension point with a `menuContribution` that has its `locationURI`-attribute pointing to `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions`. This `menuContribution` can include a `command`-element (achieving the goal of binding directly to an existing command), and this `command`-element´s `visibleWhen`-element can be bound to the activation status of the bound command's handler via the `checkEnabled`-attribute (achieving the goal of having the popup-menu entry visible only when the enablement for the command handler is satisfied).

What's bad is that the documentation of the `org.eclipse.ui.menus`-extension point states that the `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus`-extension point is to be considered deprecated, but the documentation of `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` does not mention this fact.

Comment: In 4.x the action extension points are deprecated.  But in 3.x (likes 3.6) it would only serve to generate thousands of build warnings, so instead of deprecating the extension point we just encourage use of org.eclipse.ui.menus.

Comment: I think at least the documentation must mention it as a warning sign if no plans to make it @depricated yet

Comment: Interesting forum thread related to this: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/856116/