# Eclipse RCP Compare with each other command

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I am working on an Eclipse RCP application built on 3.x and has been softly merged into 4.x.

I wish to add the Compare with Each Other menu item like in Package Explorer to a directory view I have created. There is no option in the available commands by Eclipse for this action. Going through some Eclipse code, the way they have done is to use an objectContribution via the org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus extension but that has been deprecated.

Does this mean that I will have to implement a compare with "from scratch"?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the compare action `org.eclipse.compare.internal.CompareAction` it uses `CompareUI.openCompareEditorOnPage` which is a defined API so can be used. The compare editor input used is `org.eclipse.compare.internal.ResourceCompareInput` which is internal but doesn't appear to use any other internal classes - so you could write your own version of `ResourceCompareInput` without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of contributing to popupMenu extension point, you now contribute to the menu extension point with a location URI that directs to popupMenu location.

[See this StackOverflow post to get a better explanation of the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915550/missing-link-between-objectcontribution-and-command).

As far as the code that actually implements the Compare with each other handler for the Compare with each other command, if you have access to the old code, you probably can reuse the handling of menu event, provided you wire it to the new menu event.

Comment: I know how to contribute to the popup menu. My question was more for the "Compare With Each Other" menu item that is available in the context menu of the package explorer.

Comment: If it is there, then you only need to find the code that implemented the menu listener that listens to the context menu, and the find where it dispatches the request.  That receiving handler has the code, and probably will provide the bulk of what you are looking for; however, if you have even a slightly "different than what's there" need, you probably won't be able to determine what is reusable until after you look at that handler.  Might be an easy tweak, might not be.

Comment: The action is in one of the internal classes of Eclipse. So it means I will probably have to write my own compare with editor.