# Adding custom right click menu into Eclipse's project explorer view in RCP application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently I'm using Eclipse's Project Explorer view into my RCP Application by writing the following line of command into my "Perspective.java" file...

`layout.addView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.30f, editorArea);`

It is currently giving me all the default right click options that eclipse's project explorer view gives..
i.e. cut, copy, paste, delete, refresh, etc.

I want to add my own custom right click options into these default options. Does anyone know how to do it? Or will have to build my own project explorer view??

Is there anyway from where i can get the code that eclipse used for building the project explorer view?

would like to know what can be done in this situation or any other solution for this??

Thankyou !!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu

Comment: There's a lot you can do with Eclipse to add your own functionality, you should have a look at some tutorials and articles regarding Eclipse plugins, such as http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html

Comment: Thanx Calon..that actually helped me!! wanted to ask you one more thing. How to get the control of project, module and files....i mean if user clicks on the project how do we come to know that it's actually project and not the folder and files. By adding the project explorer view in the above discussed question, what is the way to get the control of the selected project/folder/files?

Comment: got the solution !! :)

IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();

IViewPart viewPart = page.findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
ISelectionProvider selProvider = viewPart.getSite().getSelectionProvider();
  
System.out.println("output is "+selProvider.getSelection());

Comment: If you have the choice, I'd recommend you to go for Eclipse 4 instead and use Dependency Injections: @Inject
private ESelectionService selectionService; System.out.println(selecionService.getSelection(partId));

Comment: I've already finished half of my application development !! Is there any way to migrate from eclipse 3.7 to 4 with an existing development !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my comment covers your question, the follow up questions need some more space:
a) how to look at eclipse sources:

```
*File -> Import ... ->Plug-in Development -> Plug-ins and Fragments -> Next*
Chose *Import as -> Binary Projects* (you can read the source code but not change it. This saces time, because the code doesn't get compiled) ->Next
Chose plugins to import -> Finish
You can find the sources in the projects in "referenced libraries"
```

b) you need the path to the menu entry and the plugin you want to add to. This can be done with the Plugin spy (Alt+Shift+F1 -> click on the view of which you want to get the id) or or Menu-Spy (Alt+Shift+F2 -> click on the menu entry that you want to add to)in Eclipse.

c) To add a menu entry to the popup, see the [How to add items in popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu) (the one I mentioned in my comment).