# Contributing a custom delete handler to the project explorer context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In an Eclipse plugin I have a custom `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent` extension. I am trying to provide a custom Delete handler. Previously I was using the `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point and with a `objectContribution/action`, but that does not support key bindings due to [Eclipse bug #329979: [Key Bindings] Support keybinding of objectContributions](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=32979).

I've tried a couple of approaches:

*Defining a handler for the delete command*

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
       commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
       class="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.actions.JcrNodeDeleteHandler">
       <activeWhen>
           <adapt type="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.model.JcrNode"/>
       </activeWhen>
    </handler>
</extension>
```

*Registering a custom delete action in my actionProvider*

I've registered an actionProvider for my custom navigatorContent.

```xml
<actionProvider
      class="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.PackageExplorerOpenActionProvider"
      id="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.actions.OpenActions"
      overrides="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.navigator.actions.OpenActions">
    <enablement>
        <instanceof value="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.model.JcrNode"/>
    </enablement>
</actionProvider>
```

Then in that ActionProvider I've registered the action

```java
@Override
public void fillActionBars(IActionBars actionBars) {

    actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.DELETE.getId() ,deleteAction);
}
```

None of them produced the desired effect, so now I'm stuck.

How can I provide a custom implementation of the delete command for my custom navigator that also reacts to keybindings?

**Update**

I've been able to register the delete command using the following:

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
       locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions">
       <command
             commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
             icon="icons/ovr16/delete_obj.gif"
             mnemonic="D"
             label="Delete">
             <visibleWhen
                   checkEnabled="false">
                 <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                     <adapt
                           type="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.model.JcrNode">
                     </adapt>    
                 </iterate>
             </visibleWhen>
       </command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

It's important to note that the `visibleWhen` condition must match the one from the `handler` declaration.

However, it's not located where I would expect the 'delete' action to be, but in the 'general' area with the Run As contributions, etc. This is probably due to the `menuLocation` value of `popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=additions`, but I'm not sure what the correct value would be.

Comment: Have you looked at using the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.deleteParticipants` extension point to participate in all deletes.

Comment: @greg-449 - do you have an example about how that can be used? At the moment I have no dependency on ltk and my main issue is that the 'delete' action menu is not even present

Comment: Defining a handler for `org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete` should work. Do you explicitly contribute the command within your navigator extension or is it contributed from elsewhere (built-in)? Did you try to add `enabledWhen` with the same condition as in `activeWhen`?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann - see my update - the actionProvider is contributed from by contentNavigator. I am not sure what you mean about contributing the command - I only define a handler for it. Should I do something else?

Also see my reply, I was able to solve the issue programatically, but I'm still looking for a declarative way.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The `actionProvider` is what I meant with _explicitly contribute_, in contrast to if the delete command is contributed by someone else (e.g. JDT) and you only provide the handler. What exactly happens if you only declare the handler? Is there a Delete item in the context menu? Is it _yours_? The key binding does nothing, right? But is `HandlerProxy::execute()` invoked?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann If I only declare the handler then the command is not listed in the context menu ( not mine, not any other ). Pressing delete ( the bound key ) does nothing. The execute method of my handler is not invoked at all. Not sure what you mean with `HandlerProxy` - I don't find that class anywhere

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann - I think I managed to register the handler, but it's in the wrong location - see the updates on the question. Any hints about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register the command declaratively, in addition to a `handler` for the delete command a `menuContribution/command` must be registered as well.

```xml
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
    <menuContribution
       locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any?after=group.edit">
       <command
             commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
             icon="icons/ovr16/delete_obj.gif"
             mnemonic="D"
             label="Delete">
             <visibleWhen
                   checkEnabled="false">
                 <iterate ifEmpty="false">
                     <adapt
                           type="org.apache.sling.ide.eclipse.ui.nav.model.JcrNode">
                     </adapt>    
                 </iterate>
             </visibleWhen>
       </command>

    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Some points to note:

1. The `locationURI` specifies `?after=group.edit`. That part is important as the `group.edit` is the id of the menu which typically holds the delete/copy/paste actions
2. The `visibleWhen` must match exactly what is declared in the command. I mistakenly used only the `adapt` tag, but it must be wraped inside an `iterate` tag. I seem to recall that this is due to the `IStructuredSelection` being validated against the criteria

Thanks to [Rüdiger Herrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2986905/r%C3%BCdiger-herrmann) for guiding me towards the right answer. Also see [How to add items in popup menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342532/how-to-add-items-in-popup-menu), which has valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach to register the command programatically is to override the `fillContextMenu` method:

```
@Override
public void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu) {

    super.fillContextMenu(menu);
    if ( deleteAction != null ) {
        menu.appendToGroup(ICommonMenuConstants.GROUP_EDIT, renameAction);
    }
}
```